# Issue with many 1:M scenario in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, database-design, relational-database

First time posting. Long time reader!

I've recently started delving into Access. I have some background/slash knowledge with databasing and I've made good progress on my little project - however, I am stumped when it comes to nesting/many one-to-many's. I'm trying to work it all out as an algorithm first, instead of continuing on in frustration. I vaguely remember that in SQL you can have parent and child forms, where the child form each parent is persistent. Is that the same with MS Access Subforms?

Maybe its a limitation of Access, or maybe I'm just a muppet noob - so I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction!

**Scenario:**

Let's consider a building/office: This building has Doors and Rooms. For the sake of the question, let's only consider the Doors and Rooms.

In my scenario, a Room can have multiple doors, whereas a Door can only have a maximum of two Rooms (the two rooms that it joins).

I have a table of Doors and a table of Rooms, each with a PK.

I want to have a list of Doors, that demonstrates what Rooms they are associated with (should only ever be two) and I also want a register of Rooms, that lists all Doors associated with the Room.

**Problem 1:** So considering the Rooms scenario, how would I associate it with the Doors Table, in such a way that I can have multiple entries linked to the Room Table. I'm assuming a join them through a third table that links Rooms and Doors.

**Problem 2:** In relation to the Doors scenario, what would be the best way? Would I make two columns/fields in the Door Table, like Room_A and Room_B, or would I somehow join them through a third table?

**Problem 3:** Further to this, I will need to make a list of all Doors that are accessible in both Room_A and Room_B. I think this part won't be so hard once the two other problems are dealt with.

Before anyone jumps in and says "upload a screenshot you douchebag" - I can't upload anything at the moment. I'll try and upload something later today.

Thanks in advance for any info!

Comment: Sounds like a 2:Many relationship to me, which is many-to-many since anything greater than 1 is many. You can use a junction table. If you need help with queries, you should try posting sample data, and expected output based on that. Most activity on SO is within the first few hours, if you can't complete the question you're better off posting it when you can instead of adding information to it later.

Comment: Please use text, not images/links, for text, including tables & (possibly pseudo-)DDL for ERDs; use images for info beyond that.

Comment: Hi. Time to read a textbook on information modeling & database design. PS For no doorless rooms & no room- or door-specific data, a situation can be characterized by base table portal(r,d) --"room r has door d". Then we query for derived tables. As usual this design is constrained to certain values (managed via declarations & triggers) & we can have different designs trading simplifications for complications. Investigate other designs--bases & constraints & corresponding queries. Under this comment's assumptions there's probably no more straightforward design. PS Please read & act on [mcve].